# Mongoose create multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, database-schema, database-performance

What way would I go to save 40 different types of crimes, that each have and id and chance?

How would I get the ids, chance and update them?

What I got so far:

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var crime_modelSchema   = new Schema({
    userid : String,
    crimes: [
         {
            id: {type: Number, default: 1},
            chance: { type: Number, default: 50}
         }
    ],
    ip: String,
    time: Number,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('crime_model', crime_modelSchema);
```

Is this the way to go or am I far?

Comment: Schema seems to be fine but you can show what you have tried to get the ids, chance and update them?

Comment: Is the scema the way to do IT properly  , since it's over 30+ arrays ?

Comment: arrays? i think you mean arrays of objects. correct me if i am wrong. Also your schema is fine but you can also create a separate schema for crimes and embed it in your main schema. Just in case if you want to make it simple.

Answer (score 0):

For specific user:

```
db.crime_model.update({userid: user_id_you_want, "crimes.id": crimes_id_you want}, {$set: {"crimes.$.chance": 'update chnace'}});
```

For all user with  specific crime id

```
db.crime_model.update({"crimes.id": crimes_id_you want}, {$set: {"crimes.$.chance": 'update chnace'}}, {multi: true});
```

Get id, chance you can directly retrieve the crime

```
db.crime_model.find({}, {crimes: 1})
```